# echo ![alt causes event not found

Tags: bash, echo

Simply run

```
echo "This is a **test** see ![alt text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png)"
```

You get:

```
bash: ![alt: event not found
```

Why? It's expected `This is a **test** see ![alt text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png)`

Comment: You can retain the double-quotes as in your example, but prevent history expansion by removing the special treatment of the `!` variable. Add a ``\`` before `!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use single quotes

```
echo 'This is a **test** see ![alt text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png)'
```

single quotes take the test you pass as verbatim. While double quoted strings are interpreted by bash, for instance `$VAR` would indicate a variable, `$(..)` would execute a command and insert the stdout, and `[...]` are treated as boolean evaluator and `!` as NOT, and so on. From the bash manual:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the  exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $ and` retain their special meaning withindouble quotes.  The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: $,  `, ",  \,  or .  A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an !  appearing in double quotes is escaped using a  backslash.   The  backslash preceding the !  is not removed.

Comment: What is the difference between single and double quotes in echo?

Comment: I expanded the answer to reply your question

Answer (score 0):

The `!` is interpreted as the NOT (logical NOT) operator and thus `[alt` is treated as a *command*. Using single quotes is probably the best option here:

```
 echo 'This is a **test** see ![alt text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png)'
```